# Uso del operador [] ambigua pero sólo tengo una versión de dicho operador

Tags: c++, operadores

He encontrado un problema en mi proyecto en que el compilador se queja de una llamada ambigua al operador de indexado (los corchetes `[]`). Ha sucedido tras añadir un operador de conversión a booleano para una clase (antes funcionaba bien). Un ejemplo simplificado sería:

```
struct S
{
    int s;
    int operator[](const std::string &) { ... }
    operator bool() const { ... }
};
```

Cuando uso el objeto `S`:

```
S s;

if (s)
    std::cout << s["hola"];
else
    std::cout << s["mundo"];
```

El compilador se queja de la ambigüedad del operador de indexado:

> ```
> error: use of overloaded operator '[]' is ambiguous (with operand types 'S' and 'const char [5]')
>     std::cout << s["hola"];
>                  ~^~~~~~~
> note: candidate function
> int operator[](const std::string &) { return s; }
>     ^
> note: built-in candidate operator[](long, const char *)
>     std::cout << s["hola"];
>                   ^
> note: built-in candidate operator[](long, const volatile char *)
> error: use of overloaded operator '[]' is ambiguous (with operand types 'S' and 'const char [6]')
>     std::cout << s["mundo"];
>                  ~^~~~~~~~
> note: candidate function
> int operator[](const std::string &) { return s; }
>     ^
> note: built-in candidate operator[](long, const char *)
>     std::cout << s["mundo"];
>                   ^
> note: built-in candidate operator[](long, const volatile char *)
> ```

Si elimino la conversión a booleano funciona:

```
struct S
{
    int s;
    int operator[](const std::string &) { ... }
    //operator bool() const { ... }
    bool es_valido() const { ... }
};

S s;

if (s.es_valido())
    std::cout << s["hola"];
else
    std::cout << s["mundo"];
```

No entiendo por qué surge este error al añadir un operador no relacionado al objeto ¿Alguna pista?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Problema.

Este error se debe a la manera en cómo funciona el operador de indexado en C++, si consultamos [el estándar de C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) en el apartado de Indexado (traducción y resaltado míos):

> #### 5.2.1 Indexado
>
> 1. Una expresión sufijo seguida de una expresión en corchetes es una expresión de indexado. Una de las expresiones debe tener el tipo “arreglo de `T`” o “puntero a `T`” y la otra debe ser un tipo enumerado sin contexto o integral. El resultado es de tipo “`T`”. El tipo “`T`” debe ser un tipo completamente definido. **La expresión `E1[E2]` es idéntica (por definición) a `*((E1)+(E2))`**.

Esta manera de indexar hace que en C++ (y en [c](/questions/tagged/c)) sea válido indexar un arreglo de manera [conmutativa](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conmutatividad):

- `arreglo[índice]`.
- `índice[arreglo]`.

Así pues, tu objeto `S` dispone de un operador de indexado (mediante `std::string`) explícito y otro implícito (y auto-generado) que indexa una cadena de caracteres con un número. ¿Por qué ambos son candidatos?

Al usar un literal de cadena (en tu caso `"hola"` y `"mundo"`) este literal es un arreglo de caracteres y como tal puede ser indexado. Pero para indexar necesitaríamos un número ¿de dónde se obtiene dicho número? ¡Del operador de conversión a booleano!

En C++ los valores booleanos pueden ser implícitamente convertidos a entero, así pues dado que el objeto `S` puede ser convertido a booleano y éste puede ser convertido a entero y puede usarse un entero para indexar un arreglo, el compilador interpreta:

```
s["hola"]
```

De esta manera:

- Convierte `s` a booleano, por ejemplo con el valor `false`.
- Convierte `false` a entero, con el valor `0`.
- Usa el entero para indexar el arreglo `"hola"`.

Así pues:

```
0["hola"]
```

Que es lo mismo (por propiedad conmutativa) que:

```
"hola"[0]
```

Que es `h`.

#### Solución.

Indica que la conversión a booleano debe ser explícita, así evitarás que el compilador use las conversiones implícitas:

```
struct S
{
    int s;
    int operator[](const std::string &) { ... }
    explicit operator bool() const { ... }
};
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Wandbox 三へ( へ՞ਊ ՞)へ ﾊｯﾊｯ](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1yksr6XVOzUkakJE)</kbd>.